# Error when run become=yes to try and get sudo access

Tags: module, ansible, root, sudo

So I am trying to run a ansible playbook with become=yes because when I run it as my normal user he has no permission and the playbook fails. But he has sudo access on the server if I run commands manually. I can reach the other server and playbooks run without become=yes when I do things in my own home directory on the slave server. But that's it. And when I use become=yes I get this error and I don't know how to fix it. Can someone please help me. This is the error below

```
PLAY [install ansible] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [h0011146.associatesys.local]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {}, "changed": false, "failed_modules": {"setup": {"failed": true, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to h0011146.associatesys.local closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}}, "msg": "The following modules failed to execute: setup\n"}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
h0011146.associatesys.local : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

koebra@h0011145: /etc/ansible/roles>
```

**THIS IS MY HOSTS FILE**

```
#
# It should live in /etc/ansible/hosts
#
#   - Comments begin with the '#' character
#   - Blank lines are ignored
#   - Groups of hosts are delimited by [header] elements
#   - You can enter hostnames or ip addresses
#   - A hostname/ip can be a member of multiple groups

[slave]
h0011146.associatesys.local     ansible_connection=ssh    ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python  #  ansible_user=root
```

**This is the playbook that fails**

```
---

- name: install ansible
  hosts: slave
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: install
    yum:
      name: ansible
      state: latest
```

**THIS IS THE FULL OUTPUT OF -VVV**

```
koebra@h0011145: /etc/ansible/roles> ansible-playbook ansible.yml 

PLAY [install ansible] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
^C [ERROR]: User interrupted execution
koebra@h0011145: /etc/ansible/roles> ansible-playbook ansible.yml -vvv
ansible-playbook 2.9.10
 config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
 configured module search path = [u'/home/koebra/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
 ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
 executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
 python version = 2.7.5 (default, Jun 11 2019, 14:33:56) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
host_list declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
script declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
Parsed /etc/ansible/hosts inventory source with ini plugin

PLAYBOOK: ansible.yml *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
1 plays in ansible.yml

PLAY [install ansible] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/roles/ansible.yml:3
<h0011146.associatesys.local> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<h0011146.associatesys.local> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/koebra/.ansible/cp/8a6e5420a0 h0011146.associatesys.local '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~ && sleep 0'"'"''
<h0011146.associatesys.local> (0, '/home/koebra\n', '')
<h0011146.associatesys.local> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<h0011146.associatesys.local> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/koebra/.ansible/cp/8a6e5420a0 h0011146.associatesys.local '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /home/koebra/.ansible/tmp `"&& mkdir /home/koebra/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1606933213.23-55559-199169178631287 && echo ansible-tmp-1606933213.23-55559-199169178631287="` echo /home/koebra/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1606933213.23-55559-199169178631287 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
<h0011146.associatesys.local> (0, 'ansible-tmp-1606933213.23-55559-199169178631287=/home/koebra/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1606933213.23-55559-199169178631287\n', '')
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/system/setup.py
<h0011146.associatesys.local> PUT /home/koebra/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-55549z92f94/tmpO76wSg TO /home/koebra/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1606933213.23-55559-199169178631287/AnsiballZ_setup.py
<h0011146.associatesys.local> SSH: EXEC sftp -b - -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/koebra/.ansible/cp/8a6e5420a0 '[h0011146.associatesys.local]'
<h0011146.associatesys.local> (0, 'sftp> put /home/koebra/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-55549z92f94/tmpO76wSg /home/koebra/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1606933213.23-55559-199169178631287/AnsiballZ_setup.py\n', '')
<h0011146.associatesys.local> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<h0011146.associatesys.local> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/koebra/.ansible/cp/8a6e5420a0 h0011146.associatesys.local '/bin/sh -c '"'"'chmod u+x /home/koebra/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1606933213.23-55559-199169178631287/ /home/koebra/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1606933213.23-55559-199169178631287/AnsiballZ_setup.py && sleep 0'"'"''
<h0011146.associatesys.local> (0, '', '')
<h0011146.associatesys.local> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<h0011146.associatesys.local> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/koebra/.ansible/cp/8a6e5420a0 -tt h0011146.associatesys.local '/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo -H -S -n  -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-xlbmctdergsnsmfzmvctpkiayaendarz ; /usr/bin/python /home/koebra/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1606933213.23-55559-199169178631287/AnsiballZ_setup.py'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''
Escalation succeeded
<h0011146.associatesys.local> (1, '', 'Shared connection to h0011146.associatesys.local closed.\r\n')
<h0011146.associatesys.local> Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Shared connection to h0011146.associatesys.local closed.
<h0011146.associatesys.local> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<h0011146.associatesys.local> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/koebra/.ansible/cp/8a6e5420a0 h0011146.associatesys.local '/bin/sh -c '"'"'rm -f -r /home/koebra/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1606933213.23-55559-199169178631287/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'"'"''
<h0011146.associatesys.local> (0, '', '')
fatal: [h0011146.associatesys.local]: FAILED! => {
   "ansible_facts": {}, 
   "changed": false, 
   "failed_modules": {
       "setup": {
           "failed": true, 
           "module_stderr": "Shared connection to h0011146.associatesys.local closed.\r\n", 
           "module_stdout": "", 
           "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", 
           "rc": 1
       }
   }, 
   "msg": "The following modules failed to execute: setup\n"
}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
h0011146.associatesys.local : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

THIS WAS THE OUTPUT IN /VAR/LOG/MESSAGES OF MASTER SERVER

```
Dec  2 12:33:40 h0011145 dzdo[56701]: WARN  dz.common Username not found for given run as user cas. Error: No such file or directory
Dec  2 12:33:40 h0011145 adclient[2410]: INFO  AUDIT_TRAIL|Centrify Suite|dzdo|1.0|4|dzdo granted|5|user=koebra(type:ad,koebra@PROD-AM.AMERITRADE.COM) pid=56701 utc=1606934020062 centrifyEventID=30004 DASessID=df052d84-b898-d44b-81ff-6eeced715fc4 DAInst=N/A status=GRANTED service=dzdo command=/usr/bin/tail runas=root role=ad.role.unix.admin/Unix env=(none) MfaRequired=false EntityName=prod-am.ameritrade.com\\h0011145
koebra@h0011145: /etc/ansible/roles>
```

Comment: You should run ansible-playbook in debug mode (`-vvv`) to see if you can get any info of why this connection is closed. Does the `koebra` user have sufficient rights to connect to your remote target ? Does it have the right to sudo without restrictions ?

Comment: If this is really all you have in your output (but I doubt...), you now have to find out why your get a shared connection closed, either in your local computer log or on the remote sshd log.